# How to read a PDF file in external browser in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I have an app which shows the client's website in a webview. Said website *may* show links to PDF documents, which I get to download with this code snippet

```
webView?.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            i.data = Uri.parse(url)
            activity?.startActivity(i)
        }
```

However, this opens the external browser in the last visited website, and I'd like for it to open the PDF file itself or, at least, give an option to read it online. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A WebView cannot display a .pdf file.

Comment: Good to know. Any ideas on how to have the external browser display the PDF file (or, at least give the choice read/download) instead of going straight for the download?

Comment: Use Intent.ACTION_VIEW to let the user select the app with which the pdf should be displayed.

Comment: I already use that intent. We test it against freshly created emulators (no third party apps) to take into account less savvy users. The option there is using Chrome, but it shows the last open tab while downloading the PDF file, and I'd like to make the user experience better: either do the download without showing the browser (don't know if that's possible) or if the browser must be seen, have the browser display the PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the syntax in Kotlin, but what I use in Java (which works as expected) is this:

```
                if (url != null) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
```

Maybe you need to validate that you are getting a valid URL, and that you are calling the correct 'setter' method for the data object.

Comment: Except for the null checking, your code is the java version of mine. Thing is, if I was getting an invalid URL I shouldn't be downloading the PDF files, should I?

Comment: This method may be invoked for any number of reasons, but you can't assume that the URL is populated, so, you should check. You should also check if you actually get any data from the parse(url) call before starting the activity.  In my code, I'm using the intent's 'setData' setter method, where in your code, you are assigning the value directly to the intent's data property... it's not the same thing, though, may be the correct syntax for Kotlin.  Just highlighted it as one more thing to verify.